# Which sensor is this?

Tags: vw, sensor

My vehicle is a 2015 Volkswagen Passat Wolfsburg edition. I ran over a squirrel the other day on the driver side of my car and it has done some damage to my bumper shield and also a sensor. This is the picture of the wiring harness that the sensor connects to (sorry it was not as clear as I hoped it would be)[image]

It has PA06 and 9805940 written on it, looking that up did not help me much. The check engine light is now also on and throws this code: U0423 and also looking that up did not help. One last thing is the TPS light keeps flashing for a minute and then stops and stays on

The sensor seemed to be connected to something that is by the driver side wheel but I have no idea where it was connected to. Any help would be appreciated

Edit: Just wanted to add that this vehicle is a california emission (not that this matter) And also the fan seems to be always on even from a cold start, wonder if the ECU is doing that as a protection measure. Also that plug has only 2 pins on it so that sensor shouldn't be that complicated I will take better pictures and post them but would appreciate any help

Comment: The PA66 is just a material code for a certain polyamide, often used in automotive. You'll find it (or similar) on almost any plastics part of your card. The long number is the part number.

Comment: Which is the drivers side of your car? Do you sit on the left or right of the passenger?

Comment: Is the thing you have in your hand still connected to the car?  If so, can you take a photo of where it is located?

Comment: https://obdii.pro/en/code/U0423

Comment: Is this plug connected to the car's wiring harness? If so, what it plugs into will be somewhere within the distance this plug can reach. What's in that space? If it's in the wheel well, it might be an ABS sensor or a remote temperature sensor or a brake pad thickness sensor.

Comment: @HandyHowie I sit on the left side. and it is connected to the car's wiring harness.

Comment: @David Yes it is connected to the wiring harness, it comes from a main set of wires and one of the wires that share that same main wire go to the horn so maybe that helps? It is also very long but I think it goes somewhere to the front of the car not towrads the wheel side

Comment: "Going to the front" suggests it may connect to a temperature sensor, either at the radiator (so it reads some aspect of engine coolant temperature) or mounted in the bodywork (perhaps behind the grill, or to the side) to read ambient air temperature.

Comment: @David would an ambient air temperature sensor throw off the TPMS light? I am going to look up that sensor for my vehicle and see if it has the same connector

Comment: @David yeah I looked it up and it definitely seems like that sensor. Thank you so much, great intuition. that was probably obvious to you but I clearly lacked it. Not used to newer cars like having so many sensors. Please post your comment as an answer and I will select it once I install it. Thanks again

Comment: Glad it was useful. Good luck on completing the repair.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have asked @David to post this as an answer but I think he forgot. He was correct, the sensor in question is the Ambient Air Temperature Sensor. Installing a new one fixed the problem, thank you all!

Comment: Thanks, @method. I didn't see your prompt, happy the information was correct.

Comment: And for future reference if you return here: the reason I didn't see your prompt was that your reference to me in the comments ("@David") was truncated, so notice wasn't sent to me, but instead went to a user (or users) named "@David." A reference to my complete username ("@DavidSupportsMonica") would have raised a flag for me.

Answer (score 1):

U0423 Refers to the  instrument cluster or the module that send data to it not receiving  valid data from one of its sensors. Translation: A squirrel dislodged it and its not happy. Check the front passenger side wheel to find the location of the sensor and how it is mounted.

Comment: I checked the passenger side and can't find anything similar to it